# Jobs email feedback

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have couple of points:

1. Feedback is public and I would like to avoid it if it is possible
2. I have preferences "remote" and "android", you also know I'm from NL, I got job alert about iOS and remote US only

Comment: Regarding the second point, each time I have flagged a listing as not being remote as per the remote tag, the team has quickly contacted me to let me know they have updated the post to reflect so

Comment: In regards to the first point - what? If you could reword that to explain what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks, but it is email, so I have to open it at the SO first

Comment: @Shadow Some question I want to be only read and answered by SO jobs developers. So I don't that other people see I'm subscribed for jobs news letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first point**, you can contact the Stack Overflow Support team [from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), and select "I need help with Stack Overflow Jobs" in the dropdown. This will send a *private* message to the support team.

**Regarding your second point**, more information would be required to troubleshoot your issue. Feel free to forward the offending email to me (`agasser@stackoverflow.com`).

To create a job alert for specific criteria, you can do a specific job search (e.g. [remote jobs with the android tag](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=%5Bandroid%5D&r=true)), and then click "Save search":

[image]

You can then select whether or not you want to be emailed whenever new jobs matching this search get published:

[image]

Note that you can review your existing alerts on the [job alerts page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/current).

Comment: I don't have that email already. But I will keep an eye on emails and contact you in case of similar issue.

Comment: The contact page you're suggesting is great. However, I pressed something like "tell us" on job position and landed up making question here.